# Voluntary fast requirements?

Tags: halacha, fast-days

If one accepts to take on a voluntary fast, is there a specific minimum or maximum time one must fast for (I.e. sunrise to sunset)?  Also with voluntary fasts is it acceptable for one to take upon a voluntary fast of only food during the required timeframe and have it count as a complete voluntary fast?

Comment: One can always accept to do any specified set of actions/non-actions. What exactly are you looking for this commitment to count as in order to qualify as "a fast"?

Comment: @DoubleAA , If one wishes to take upon a voluntary fast such as the one might declare during Mincha Amidah.  For the sake of this example, let's say a person sinned and wished to take upon a voluntary fast and stated the intent during Mincha Amidah.

Answer (score 1):

A person can accept upon themselves any type of commitment or abstinence of food or drink through a neder without the laws of a Taanis.

As far as the laws of Taanis goes, the Shulchan Aruch O"C 562:11 says:

> אם קבל עליו תענית עד חצי היום ואכל אח"כ או שאכל עד חצי היום וקבל עליו תענית משם ואילך אינו נקרא תענית להתפלל עננו אבל נקרא תענית לענין שצריך להשלים נדרו:

The Mishna Berura explains:

> מח) עד חצי היום - לאו דוקא דה"ה אם הקבלה היה עד ג' רביע היום אם דעתו לאכול קודם גמר היום אינו מתפלל ענינו בתפלת המנחה ועיין לעיל בס"א בהג"ה דהיחיד יכול לומר ענינו בש"ת:

> מט) שצריך להשלים נדרו - דה"א דמותר לאכול תוך אותו זמן שקיבל עליו דלא הוי נדר כלל קמ"ל דמ"מ צריך להתענות אותו זמן:

This means that the Taanis is the same as any neder, although there was a possibility that since its not considered a real fast it shouldn't even have the level of a neder, the halacha is its still a neder and he must fast the amount of time he specified. Yet he can't say Aneinu. In order to be able to say Aneinu and have the law of Taanis, the Shulchan Aruch says in 562:1

> כל תענית שלא שקעה עליו חמה דהיינו שלא השלימו עד צאת הכוכבים דהיינו שיראה ג' כוכבים בינונים או שהלבנה זורחת בכח ותאיר על הארץ (הגהות אשירי פ"ק דתענית והגהות מיימוני פ"א) אינו תענית ואם דעתו לאכול קודם לכן אינו מתפלל עננו:

The Rama argues and says one could say Aneinu if he fasted until Mincha

> הגה מיהו נוהגין להתפלל עננו אע"פ שאין משלימין עד צאת הכוכבים וכן דעת מקצת רבוותא (תה"ד סי' קנ"ז) ונראה לי דדוקא ביחיד דאומר עננו בשומע תפלה דבלאו הכי יכול להוסיף כמו שנתבאר לעיל סי' קי"ט אבל שליח ציבור לא יאמר עננו אא"כ משלימין וכן נוהגין:

The Mishna Berura explains the Rama:

> אף על פי שאין משלימין - והא דסתם רמ"א להקל בפירש בשעת קבלה היינו דוקא במתפלל תפלת מנחה קודם אכילתו אבל כשאכל מתחלה בכל גווני אינו מתפלל עננו:

> וכן דעת מקצת רבוותא - טעמם דס"ל דמה שאמר הגמרא כל תענית שלא שקעה עליו חמה אינו תענית והיינו אף לענין עננו הוא רק אם קיבל עליו להתענות יום שלם ולא השלים דאינו תענית אז אינו מתפלל עננו אבל אם קיבל עליו רק עד מנחה דהוא לצעורי בעלמא הוי תענית לענין זה שמתפלל עננו בתוך תפלתו אף שאיננו משלים אכן רוב הפוסקים חולקים ע"ז וע"כ הכריע רמ"א דלא נסמוך עליה רק לענין יחיד דיאמרנה בש"ת ויחתום כי אתה שומע וכו' ולא יאמר בא"י העונה בעת צרה

So, although he says it's just to cause pain, the Rama still holds it has some level of Taanis and one can say Aneinu